# Why do I have a dependency to gwt?

Tags: java, deployment, gwt, jboss, seam

In a seam-gen generated application the following exception is thrown during deployment:

```
ERROR [LoadMgr3] Not resheduling failed loading task, loadTask=org.jboss.mx.loading.ClassLoadingTask@8c5c9c{classname: org.jboss.seam.remoting.gwt.GWT14Service, requestingThread: Thread[ScannerThread,5,jboss], requestingClassLoader: org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader3@3e4532{ url=f
ile:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/myapp.ear/ ,addedOrder=50}, loadedClass: nullnull, loadOrder: 2147483647, loadException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/SerializationPolicyProvider, threadTaskCount: 0, state: 1, #CCE: 1}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/SerializationPolicyProvider
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
...
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:610)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:225)
```

The problem (and workaround) is described [here](http://seamframework.org/Community/NoClassDefFoundExceptionOnGoogleSerializationPolicyProvider).
Since I don't use gwt, my question is why do I have this dependency when I'm not using gwt at all?

Seam version 2.1.2

EDIT:
Just for the records: Until another solution is available I added `gwt-servlet.jar` in the file `deployed-jars-ear.list` this satisfies the deployment scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see Ant Target responsible for copying libraries used by Seam-gen

```
<target name="copy-lib" depends="copyseam, copyseamdependencies, copyjbossembedded, copy-icefaces-home, copy-icefaces-maven">
    <echo message="Copying Seam and dependencies to the ${project.home}/lib directory..."/>

    <copy todir="${project.home}/lib" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${seam.dir}/lib">
            <exclude name="jsf-facelets.jar" if="icefaces.property"/>
            <exclude name="ajax4jsf*.jar" if="icefaces.property"/>
            <exclude name="richfaces*.jar" if="icefaces.property"/>
            <exclude name="jboss-container.jar"/>
            <exclude name="jboss-seam-wicket.jar"/>
            <exclude name="jboss-seam-resteasy.jar"/>
            <exclude name="test/jboss-deplyers.jar"/>
            <exclude name="test/jboss-embedded-api.jar"/>
            <exclude name="interop/**/*"/>
            <exclude name="gen/**/*"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset file="${driver.jar}"/>
    </copy>

    <!-- we must use an endorsed jars directory containing JAXB 2.1 for running SeamTest under Java 6 -->
    <copy todir="${project.home}/lib/endorsed" file="${seam.dir}/lib/gen/jaxb-api.jar" overwrite="true"/>

    <echo message="Copying JBoss Embedded configuration to the ${project.home}/bootstrap directory..."/>
    <copy todir="${project.home}/bootstrap" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${seam.dir}/bootstrap"/>
    </copy>

</target>
```

Notice it is **not exclude** GWT library. But As far i know, Seam **does not depends on** GWT library. So you can set up your custom exclude. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453746/jboss-seam-enabling-debug-page-on-weblogic-10-3-2-11g/2459795#2459795) you can see how your Seam app should looks like.

The build.xml file Seam-gen uses is located in

<SEAM_HOME>/seam-gen/build.xml

Comment: Thanks, but there is no other jar in the lib dir but gwt-servlet.jar which name indicates that it could be involved in this issue.

Comment: @stacker Have you seen Chris Bauer comment: http://seamframework.org/Community/NoClassDefFoundExceptionOnGoogleSerializationPolicyProvider#comment72922

Comment: @arthur-ronald-f-d-garcia thanks he says it's logged as DEBUG (including the exception) and user shouldn't worry. Now I'm relaxed and if I have time I'm going to find out why this appears as error.

Comment: For the records I excluded gwt-servlet.jar and jboss-seam-remoting.jar

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some part of seam just depends on classes from the `gwt-servlet.jar`.

Bet you have to take it as it is and hope for a code cleanup on seam's side, because it is surprising that your're required to add 'gwt' libs to your project even if you do not use gwt.

Comment: We can still hope for another answer with a solution how to get rid of this dependency ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, checking on my seam project, the awt library is an internal dependecie for some faces modules, you just need to be sure to add gwt-servlet-2.3.0.jar to your

Project-ear.ear\Project.war\WEB-INF\lib