# Insert external data into persistence.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want my persistence.xml to set some of its properties dynamically, to be specific:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username"/>
```

I can build a class that could provide me the data I need, but I don't know how to set the class up in a way that it works like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${my.clazz.pass}"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="${my.clazz.user}"/>
```

I have tried to set the class up like this

```
public class clazz{

  String pass;
  String user;

  public clazz(){
    //do stuff to set pass and user
  }

  //getter/setter
}
```

But that does not work. I haven't found a way here or in google, but I have seen the ${my.clazz.smth}-way several times.

So, how can I set that up? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are running a web application you should consider using JNDI lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, resolved this a while ago, but I still didn't answer:

Anthony Accioly pointed me to the right direction:

I added this to my applicationContext.xml's entityManagerFactory

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
        <bean class="my.package.SetupDatabase">
        </bean>
    </property>
    //the other stuff
</bean>
```

The corresponding class, in this case I use hibernate:

```
package my.package;

public class SetupDatabase implements PersistenceUnitPostProcessor {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String dbserver;

    public void SetupDatabase(){
        //do stuff to obtain needed information
    }

    public void postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(MutablePersistenceUnitInfo pui) {
        pui.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username );
        pui.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        pui.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", dbserver ); 
    }

}
```

This way the setup is done just once when starting the whole thing up, but the required data may be 'outsourced'.

Thanks again for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: I need to do the same but without spring. Any tips in my case?

Comment: The class `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` contains also the property `jpaProperties`, which would achieve the same without requiring a `PersistenceUnitPostProcessor`.

Comment: @DanielArdison for your question is probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4548353/208576) relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The value placeholder `${my.clazz.smth}` that you refer to is usually read from a properties file as opposed to a class directly.

This is done using Spring's [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html).

Here is an [example](http://codeyard.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/spring-hibernate-end-to-end-integration-using-maven-spring-mvc-jsp-oracle11g-a-step-by-step-guide/) of a project which combined the Hibernate & Spring.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to delay the configuration until runtime (e.g., to obtain the database credentials from an external source such as a Web service) you can do it with [Hibernate API Programatic Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-programmatic), particularly [Ejb3Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/Ejb3Configuration.html) for legacy versions of Hibernate or [ServiceRegistryBuilder](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistryBuilder.html) (v 4.X)...

But be warned that, to the best of my knowledge, there is no way to dynamically update the username and password of a `PersintenceUnit`. You will have to build another `EntityManagerFactory` from a new `Configuration` instance (a quite expensive operation) every time that you need to change it's properties.
Anyway, unless you have a really good reason to, do not manage database credentials from your application, delegate it to a JNDI-Bound `DataSource` instead.

```
Ejb3Configuration cfg = new Ejb3Configuration()
  // Add classes, other properties, etc
  .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "xxxx")
  .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "yyyy"); 

EntityManagerFactory emf= cfg.buildEntityManagerFactory();
```

Comment: Exactly, I get the credentials from another service, but I only need to set them once when starting the server and won't let them be directly visible on the source. I'll give your advice a try and post a solution if I find one :)