# Externalize dynamic properties in persistence.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa

We are using the bellow properties in our persistence.xml file.

```
<properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XYZDB01:78111:TATAD1" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin@123" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.Schema" value="CSMVC" />
</properties>
```

But I want to externalize the dynamic properties from persistence.xml something like bellow.

```
<properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.dialect" value="${db.dialect}" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${db.user}" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${db.password}" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.Schema" value="${db.schema}" />
</properties>
```

Note: We are using openJpa as the JPA provider.

Comment: Are you using Spring Framework?

Comment: No. We don't use Spring.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013222/insert-external-data-into-persistence-xml

Comment: Note: A property named `javax.persistence.jdbc.dialect` is not mentioned in the Java EE 7 specification.

Comment: And when would tha be resolved? At startup? What would be the source of values? Another xml?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would define your datasource in your container and have JPA look it up via JNDI. Are you running JPA in Spring/TomEE/Tomcat/Wildfly/Liberty or anything else?