# What is the recommended source control ignore pattern for Seam projects?

Tags: svn, git, mercurial, jboss, seam

After generating a project using `seam-gen`, what is the recommended ignore pattern for source control? What should the recommended `.gitignore` file (or `svn:ignore`, or equivalents) look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We develop our Seam projects under Eclipse. Our current `svn:ignore` has the following entries:

```
classes                      # all class files
dist                         # contains generated war files for deployment
.settings                    # some Eclipse settings
exploded-archives            # war content generation during deploy (or explode)
test-output                  # test results
test-build                   # test compilation (ant target for Seam)
test-report                  # test report generation for, e.g., Hudson
temp-testng-customsuite.xml  # generated when running test cases under Eclipse
```

In addition, in our `bootstrap` folder we ignore `data` and `tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

I have no direct experience with seam, but if you [start a project with seam-gen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281418/should-i-start-my-seam-project-from-scratch-or-from-a-seam-gen-generated-project), then you need to:

- exclude in your `.gitignore` file whatever will contain *generated* content (like the [`target` directory](https://github.com/mbogner/mbook/blob/master/.gitignore), also [`*.sw` files or `test-output` directories](https://github.com/seam/rest/blob/master/.gitignore))
- don't exclude IDE-related files (if they don't include absolute path), in order for others to get directly a project they can import in said IDE,
- contribute back the content of the gitignore file in the **[GitHub `gitignore` project](https://github.com/github/gitignore)**: they need a seam/seam-gen entry.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the entries above, I've merged the suggestions into an entry on the gitignore project:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/SeamGen.gitignore

Comment: Didn't work for me, until I didn't remove the comments in the file. I think you cannot add comment in the same line with the rule...

Comment: based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/8865858/422476 I am editing your file on github