# How to add a comment in a .gitignore file?

Tags: git, comments, gitignore

Can you write comments in a `.gitignore` file?

If so, should the line be preceded with a `#` or some other indicator?

Comment: If you use an editor that knows about these things (e.g. Vim), the lines commented with `#` will be formatted appropriately - easy to discover yourself that way!

Comment: So you are looking for a .gitignoreignore?

Answer (score 918, accepted):

Yes, you may put comments in there. They however must start at the beginning of a line.

cf. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Ignoring-Files

> The rules for the patterns you can put in the .gitignore file are as follows:
>   - Blank lines or lines starting with # are ignored.
>   […]

The comment character is `#`, example:

```
# no .a files
*.a
```

Comment: Don't know if it was true when this was answered, but the linked book section indicates that in addition to starting a line, comments can also be _appended_ to a line in the .gitignore file.

Comment: @StuartR.Jefferys I'm on git 1.7.4.1 and am finding that a line with a comment at the end does not work:  

`src/main/log/  # Doesn't work.  git status still shows this directory`
`src/main/log/` Works fine.  git status does not show the directory.  

In fact, it appears that _any_ whitespace at the end of the line is considered part of the ignore pattern.

Comment: @Johann You are right! Trailing whitespace _is_ significant, even with directories (ending in `/`). If a file has a trailing space, the `.gitignore` entry must match; 0 or 2 spaces and it fails. I consider it a bug. I'm using git version 1.7.5.4. It _could_ be intentional, even if it probably _shouldn't_. But you can use `[ ]` as a space character specifier. That is much better than allowing trailing white-space; it allows for the rare intentional trailing space, while making the more common (and hard to see) error case detectable.

Comment: Thanks for this; I was having the hardest time trying to understand why `git` was ignoring my `.gitignore`. It was because I put **end-of-line comments** after some entries. The default VIM syntax coloring for `config` filetypes misled me.

Comment: I don't currently see anything in the linked book section about comments appended to a line, [nor do I see it in the documentation of the gitignore file's format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). And indeed, if I add a line to my gitignore that says `foo#` (notice there is no trailing nor intervening space), it ignores a file named `foo#`, and *does not* ignore a file named `foo`, clearly demonstrating that the `#` is recognized as part of the pattern and not as a comment character.

Comment: @Timo This isn't the place to speculate, but neither can I see any point to such a feature. Just put a # at the start of each comment line.

Answer (score 278):

Do `git help gitignore`.

You will get the help page with following line:

> A line starting with # serves as a comment.

Comment: +1 for pointing out how to find information, not just giving information.

Comment: @cregox - `Also, I like using computers without command lines` - git is wrong place for you then, sorry.

Comment: @manojlds `git` is right place for everyone, just like `rsync`. they just need good gui's, like dropbox. too sad we're still missing one for git...

Comment: You could also do `git help ignore` (which is supported by git bash-completion)

Comment: Agree with @manojlds that at the end of the day you'll be on the command line fixing what your IDE can't handle in Git. Some things are just trivially easy from the command line. Having said that, for complex merges I'll let Jetbrains handle it any day, I'm still in there editing things manually regardless of the GUI